# Drawing Shapes and Young Tablauex

Tags: shapes, ytableau

I would like to draw a shape, in the sense of a young tableaux with arbitrary boxes missing.

A currently have the following, which allows me to draw skew tableaux, however I want the box containing c to be removed (with a gap in its place, not just an empty box)

```
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}

\begin{document}

$\young(ab::cd,:efg)$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want a gap? Or an empty box?

Comment: I am wanting a gap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution with `ytableau`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\ytableausetup{centertableaux}
\begin{ytableau}
       a & b & \none & d \\
  \none  & e &     f & g
\end{ytableau}

\end{document}
```

[image]